# map with duplicate keys and file writing

Tags: java, file

I am trying to make an output something like this

```
project     class
kata        FizzBuzz
kata        FizzBuzzTest
kata        Anagrams    
kata        AnagramsTest
emacs4ij    BufferTest
emacs4ij    TestSetup
emacs4ij    TestFrameManagerImp
```

I have walked through the directory using `Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(path), this);` and then created a Map and put the values in it. Map doesn't allow multiple key so i only get `kata  AnagramsTest` and `emacs4ij  TestFrameManagerTmp` as values in map when I print it. Printing results on console shows that I have got all.

Here is a brief code that I have tried to do

```
public class MyFileIterator extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path>{

Map<String, String> contentMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
public MyFileIterator(String path) throws Exception{
    Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(path), this);
}

 @Override
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
        BasicFileAttributes attributes) throws IOException{
    Objects.requireNonNull(file);
    if (file.getFileName().toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".java")) {
        //getName(5) will give the Project Name
        System.out.println("project name is: "+file.getName(5));
        System.out.println("Located file: " + file.getFileName().toString());
        contentMap.put(file.getName(5).toString(),file.getFileName().toString());            
    }
    writeUsingFileWriter(contentMap);
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}
```

I have also tried it with a `Map<String, List<String>)` and `Map<List<String>, String>` but no success

For writing a file and creating the desired output I have done something like this

```
private static void writeUsingFileWriter(Map<String,String> tempMap) {

     try(Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(//maypath here))) {
         tempMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
            try { System.out.println(key + " " + value); 
                writer.write(key + " " + value + System.lineSeparator()); }
            catch (IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
        });
    } catch(UncheckedIOException | IOException ex) { ex.getCause(); }
```

And in the main method I have done something like this

```
String path = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();
    try {
        MyFileIterator temp = new MyFileIterator(path);         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So if the project is located at the following path say: C:\code\kata\FizzBuzz.java

I am trying to get the **Kata** and the **FizzBuzz** *->(may need to use tokenization or split or regex to cut this path and get the desired result...even need to cut the .java)* and put it in a map and write on a file in the format given above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What was your code with `Map<String, List<String>>`? It should work with `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Comment: You can use one of the many frameworks available for maps with duplicate key. Or just use a list of `Entry<K,V>`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your updated code. As mentioned, your issue was that you were printing all the files you visited every time you visited a new file...

```
public class MyFileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

    private Map<String, List<String>> contentMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyFileVisitor myVisitor = new MyFileVisitor();
        myVisitor.collectAllJavaFilesInFileTree(Paths.get("C:\\root\\dir"));
        myVisitor.writeUsingFileWriter(Paths.get("C:\\file\\to\\write.txt"));
    }

    public void collectAllJavaFilesInFileTree(Path root) throws IOException {
        Files.walkFileTree(root, this);
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attributes) throws IOException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(file);
        final String fileName = file.getFileName().toString();
        if (fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".java")) {
            // project name will be null if path isn't at least 5 deep...
            String projectName = null;
            if (file.getNameCount() >= 5) {
                projectName = file.getName(5).toString();
            }

            String key = projectName;
            List<String> list = contentMap.get(key);
            if (list == null) {
                list = new ArrayList<String>();
                contentMap.put(key, list);
            }
            list.add(fileName);
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }


    public void writeUsingFileWriter(Path fileToWrite) {
        try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(fileToWrite)) {
            contentMap.forEach((key, valueList) -> {
                try {
                    for (String value : valueList) {
                        writer.write(key + " " + value + System.lineSeparator());
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
                }
            });
        } catch (UncheckedIOException | IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely check it soon and update you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Map<String, List<String>>`:

```
Map<String, List<String>> contentMap = new HashMap<>();
// ...

public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attributes) throws IOException{
    Objects.requireNonNull(file);
    if (file.getFileName().toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".java")) {
        // getName(5) will give the Project Name
        System.out.println("project name is: " + file.getName(5));
        System.out.println("Located file: " + file.getFileName().toString());

        // vvv NEW STUFF vvv
        String key = file.getName(5).toString();
        List<String> list = contentMap.get(key);
        if(list == null){
            // if the list didn't exist then create it
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            contentMap.put(key, list);
        }
        list.add(file.getFileName().toString());
    }
    writeUsingFileWriter(contentMap);
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}
```

---

```
private static void writeUsingFileWriter(Map<String, List<String>> tempMap) {
    try(Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("myPath"))){
        tempMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
            try {
                for(String s : value){
                    System.out.println(key + " " + s); 
                    writer.write(key + " " + s + System.lineSeparator());
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
            }
        });
    } catch(UncheckedIOException | IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you need, you can also make convenience methods to remove things from the lists in the map and/or remove the list if there is nothing left in it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was making a mistake while extracting content from the Map previously when using the Map<String, List<String>>.

Comment: @Skipper07 Wonderful, glad it worked for you. Also, since it solved your problem, please accept this answer.

Comment: but it goes in the infinte loop. I have a corpus of size 1.4 GB and this program is running for two days on my system but no still printing. I have manually checked its not that many files Any suggestions?

Comment: @Skipper07 see edits, I added `println` in `visitFile` and `ex.printStackTrace` in `writeUsingFileWriter`, this will give you more info on what is happening. Please share the output.

Comment: As i have said it gets in to infinite loop so the whole output can't be printed here. However, I can show you some part of it. I have added two more System.out.println statements and got following. `101repo Token.java
7 8
101repo CDL.java
7 11
101repo Cookie.java
7 15
101repo CookieList.java
7 9
101repo HTTP.java
7 16
101repo HTTPTokener.java
7 14
101repo JSONArray.java
7 18
101repo JSONException.java
7 11
101repo JSONML.java
7 15
101repo JSONObject.java`

Comment: @Skipper07 Your issue is that you were re-writing your entire map of files visited every time you visited a new file. I have modified your code and am submitting it in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating comment of @NielsNet, maybe you can give `List` of `Entry` a try. Something like:

```
private final List<Map.Entry<String, String>> content = new LinkedList<>();

...

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                                     BasicFileAttributes attributes) throws IOException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(file);
        if (file.getFileName().toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".java")) {
            //getName(5) will give the Project Name
            System.out.println("project name is: " + file.getName(5));
            System.out.println("Located file: " + file.getFileName().toString());
            content.add(new SimpleEntry<>(file.getName(5).toString(), file.getFileName().toString()));
        }
...
```